# Devise added new fields now - unidentified method error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have added new fields to Devise and did rake db:migrate, etc, and it seems to work fine on local host, however on Heroku I get the following error in my logs claiming there is an unidentified method:

https://gist.github.com/1179667

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like my problem was a combination of a spelling mistake in my `user.rb` and having `zipcode` there also which wasn't in the form.